# Move UIImage horizontally with animation

Tags: ios, swift, animation

I want to move `UIImageView` horizontally from left to right and right to left.
I designed this as below.

1. UIView (green color)
2. Arrow Image (Leading of UIView, Center vertically of UIView, Fix Height, Width)
3. UILabel (Center Horizontally & center Vertically of UIView)
4. Button (Leading, Top, Trailing, Bottom of UIView)
   In above image, Green color is UIView and the left arrow icon is image. so when user press the button i want to move Arrow Image from **Left to Right** and **Right to Left** vice versa.

**EDIT 1**

Thanks for your answer

```
if sender.isSelected {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, animations: {
        self.imgVWInOut.frame.origin.x = (self.vwPunchInOut.bounds.maxX - self.imgVWInOut.bounds.width) - 10
        }) { (done) in
    }
 } else {
     UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, animations: {
         self.imgVWInOut.frame.origin.x = 10
         }) { (done) in
      }
 }
```

But when i try to change `UIView` background color and `UIImageView` image then animation not working proper.

```
@IBAction func btnPunchInOutTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected
    if sender.isSelected {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, animations: {
                self.imgVWInOut.frame.origin.x = (self.vwPunchInOut.bounds.maxX - self.imgVWInOut.bounds.width) - 10
            }) { (done) in
                self.imgVWInOut.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "ic_punchout")
                self.lblPunchInOut.text = "Punch out".localized()
                self.vwPunchInOut.backgroundColor = Colors.punchOutColor
            }
        } else {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, animations: {
                self.imgVWInOut.frame.origin.x = 10
            }) { (done) in
                self.imgVWInOut.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "ic_punchout")
                self.lblPunchInOut.text = "Punch out".localized()
                self.vwPunchInOut.backgroundColor = Colors.punchOutColor
            }
        }
}
```

**Requirement**

Default look likes this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sx15x.png)

When user press button it will look like this after animation done.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVgeS.png)

GIF Link : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1R2hfcwfhyO5JA9CQt1_6Auto3YBRj3yn/view?usp=sharing

Demo project Link  :https://drive.google.com/file/d/1H0b3D61fPIxWqSZL8tdvp0RP8juVdr_Z/view?usp=sharing

How can i achieve this. will you please help me for that.
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to animate the `frame` of `arrowImageView` w.r.t to the `customView`(green color view), i.e.

```
@IBAction func onTapButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    self.arrowImageView.frame.origin.x = self.customView.bounds.minX
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0) {
        self.arrowImageView.frame.origin.x = self.customView.bounds.maxX - self.arrowImageView.bounds.width
    }
}
```

Give the animation `duration` as per your requirement.

**EDIT:**

You need to change the `isSelected` state of `sender` on button tap,

```
@IBAction func onTapButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected //here...
    //rest of the code...
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, i want same thing like this. let me try this

Comment: @KuldeepParmar Do accept (tick on left) if you get that working.

Comment: will you please review my updated question. It works but when i try to change `UIView` BG color and `UIImageView` image then it wasn't working.

Comment: @KuldeepParmar Please elaborate your requirement for selected and not selected state.

Comment: I updated my question with requirement, will you please review this.

Comment: It is working fine with me. Try adding the code in `DispatchQueue.main.async`

Comment: @KuldeepParmar The link is not accessible.

Comment: can you please try this : https://gofile.io/d/KETavy

Comment: I found the issue, when i change label text then issue generates.

Comment: Yes, when i remove `UILabel` from subview of `UIView` and put in over `UIView` then animation won't disturb. Thanks for your help